# How to scrape next tag with bs4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am tryng to extract a table that have not a class, but have a  above it, can
I scrape this table using the title to pointing what table I want to scrape to bs4?

Have bs4 a "find_next_tag" function to scrape  from  table title?

[image: brasilian soccer championship table from wikipedia]

Comment: The HTML fragment you've shown has a table element and a class attribute. So what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS selector `+`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<h2>
    <span>Classificacao</span>
</h2>
<table>
    <tr><td>This is what I want</td></tr>
</table>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

tbl = soup.select_one('h2:-soup-contains("Classificacao") + table')
print(tbl)
```

Prints:

```html
<table>
<tr><td>This is what I want</td></tr>
</table>
```

---

Or `bs4` API (using `text=` + `.find_next()`):

```py
tbl = soup.find("span", text="Classificacao").find_next("table")
print(tbl)
```